# Чи можна вважати слово "коц" відповідником до "плед"?

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми

Слово "[плед](http://sum.in.ua/s/pled)" було запозичене від німецького "[Рlаid](https://vasmer.lexicography.online/%D0%BF/%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4)", тому я вирішив знайти відповідник. У СУМі бачимо значення слова "плед":

> Шерстяне або напівшерстяне покривало

Також там є слово "[коц](http://sum.in.ua/s/koc)", одним зі значень якого є:

> Грубе вовняне однотонне вкривало з начісками

Однак, в [словнику синонімів](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/k/koc/33-1-0-8271) до слова "коц" мені не вдалося знайти слова "плед". Отож чи можна вживати ці слова як синоніми чи все ж між ними є різниця (друге значення слова "коц" - "Ворсовий пристрижений однобічний килим")?

Answer (score 4):

Дійсно в словнику [синонімів Караванського](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53402/266735.html) не містить синоніма "плед"

> КОЦ  КОЦЬ 1. килим, ліжник; 2. рядно, укривало; Р. покривало.

Однак, якщо рознлянути визначення слів "плед" і "коц" в ВТССУМ

> [Коц](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53402/894560.html)-а, рідше коць, -я, ч. , розм. 1》 Грубе вовняне однотонне
>   вкривало з начісками. || рідко. Покривало на ліжко з якої-небудь
>   тканини. 2》 Ворсовий пристрижений однобічний килим.
>
> [Плед](http://slovopedia.org.ua/93/53407/946504.html)-а, ч. Шерстяне або напівшерстяне покривало, перев. з
>   торочками, що його використовують як хустку або ковдру.

І плед, і коц є покривалом, тому на мою думку, в деяких випадках можемо вживати слова як взаємозамінні. Підтвердження цьому знайшла в означенні слова ***"коц"*** наведеному в словнику ["Українська літературна мова на Буковині"](http://slovopedia.org.ua/103/53402/1077206.html)

> ***Коц. Плед,*** ковдра, покривало. Артикули для подорожи: нецесарія, ташки, жіночи куфри до пакованя подорожи і валізи, специяльні куфри
>   Madler-а з Липска, пуделка на капелюхи, плєди, коци (Kamelhaar),
>   анґлійскі пледи для пань і панів і т. д. (Б., 1907, рекл.)// ***пол.
>   koc - плед,*** ковдра.